# How do I notify main thread when workItem is done on background thread?

Tags: swift

There's something like `NSProgressIndicator.stopAnimation` that I have to do on main thread. However I want to do it in the end of a workItem which is assigned to background thread.

```
NSProgressIndicator.startAnimation(self)

let workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
     //
     // Some tasks
     //

     // This doesn't work, how do I call it on main thread?
     NSProgressIndicator.stopAnimation(self)
}

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async(execute: workItem)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DispatchQueue.main.async` just like you would to run any code on the main queue.

```
let workItem = DispatchWorkItem {
     //
     // Some tasks
     //

     DispatchQueue.main.async {
         NSProgressIndicator.stopAnimation(self)
     }
}
```